# Anchor tag not act properly instead show full string inside cfemail content

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cfmail

I've write a functionality about send email process. Here I've set Mail Server details admin setting. And write a below code for sending email. I can successfully send  & receive email to my gmail account. But Here I've added some paragraph with anchor tag value that is click me.

```
<cfoutput>

    <cfmail from="test@gmail.com" to="test@gmail.com" username="myemail@gmail.com" password="mypass" port="587"  subject="Chaange title" >
        <p> I'm from test link <a href="http://localhost:8501/test.cfm"> click Me 2! </a> </p>
    </cfmail>

</cfoutput>
```

The issue is in my email not received as a click me as a link. Instead it will display entire html about anchor tag. FYR please refer my email content image.

[image]

**Note :** I've already tried with cfsavecontent too but it's not help me.

Could you any one help on this. Why it's was happen ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it set up to not display HTML email? Does your email program or your group policy prevent clickable links in emails or HTML emails? Add `type="html"` to your cfmail tag. Does that change anything?

Comment: No. Even if I check with my un deliver email options in cfadmin mail setting that's also having the same UI.

Comment: And not only my specific email. I've cross check with destination of  other email id's too.

Comment: Is the issue there only for non secure links?

Comment: No. I've tried with secure links too.

Comment: As Shawn said, add the `type="html"` to your cfmail tag.

Comment: @Shawn you should consider adding as an answer

Answer (score 4):

Add `type="html"` to your `cfmail` tag. That should indicate to the end user's email client that the message should be displayed as an HTML page instead of just plain text.